# Error al devolver valores de una base de datos Acces

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Tengo el siguiente problema
Tengo una base de datos en Acces, estoy conectandome desde una aplicación de forms usando vb, al principio las consultas generaban los valores correctos, a raiz de que elimine un registro de forma manual en la BD siempre siempre me regresa un registro especifico como ultimo. Les anexo el codigo.

```
        Try
            cadena.Open()

            comando = New OleDbCommand("Insert into QRQC (Nombre,NumControl,Fecha,Hora,Turno)" &
                                       "values(txt_nombre,txt_numControl,lbl_fecha,lbl_hora,cBox_turno)", cadena)

            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", txt_nombre.Text)
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumControl", txt_numControl.Text)
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", lbl_fecha.Text)
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hora", lbl_hora.Text)
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Turno", cBox_turno.Text)
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery()

            consulta = "Select *From QRQC"
            oda = New OleDbDataAdapter(consulta, cadena)
            ods.Tables.Add("QRQC")
            oda.Fill(ods.Tables("QRQC"))


            Dim row As Integer
            row = ods.Tables("QRQC").Rows.Count - 1


            courrentId = ods.Tables("QRQC")(row)("ID_QRQC").ToString()
            frm_newPt2.lbl_folioQRQC.Text = courrentId

            cadena.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error al generar el registro en la base de datos", vbCritical, "Aviso")
            Console.WriteLine(ex)
            cadena.Close()
            GoTo skip
        End Try
```

Al ejecutarlo me arroja los siguientes valores:

[image: Valores en sistema]

y mis datos se ven de la siguiente forma:

[image: BD]

Como pueden ver mi consulta aunque especifico la posición 9 en el arreglo de datos, que deberia devolver el valor 106, me regresa un valor que no corresponde, 102 que corresponde a la posición 5 en el arreglo. ¿A que se debe este problema y como puedo resolverlo?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No fue porque eliminaste nada. Las bases de datos no aseguran ningun orden al devolver registros, salvo que especifiques una clausula order by. O sea, te va a devolver cualquier cosa

Comment: Roberto tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Qué resultados arroja la consulta? Pon en la pregunta el texto con los resultados (las filas que arroja). Lo que tú llamas resultados es una captura de pantalla de código.

Comment: El valor de la posición 9 es 118 no 106? Intentaste utilizando `Max(ID_QRQC)` en el `select`?